# Is there a way to install and use Docker on MacOS without GUI?

Tags: docker, macos

You can think about it this way, "Is there a way to use `docker` in GitHub Actions with a `macos` runner?" But it's not like I need it there. Whatever the way to gets one's hands on a MacOS environment, is there a way to install and use it w/o GUI? The whole way from installing docker to running a container.

The reason I need it is to reproduce an issue that manifests itself on MacOS in a docker container.

Comment: I successfully use [Minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/) for core Docker work, though it has a couple of limitations depending on what you're actually trying to do.  That probably wouldn't work in GitHub Actions though.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there actually is, you can use the `jobs.<job_id>.runs-on`, and here's how you do it:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macOS-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Build and test
        run: |
          docker build -t my-image .
          docker run my-image npm test
```

Comment: Have you actually tried it yourselves ([screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Z4mHpRn.png))?

Answer (score -1):

1. Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh):

```bash
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

2. Install [Docker](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/docker) using Homebrew:

```bash
brew install --cask docker
```

Is that what you're looking for? :)

Comment: Okay, how do I run a container then? I mean, imagine that you have only a terminal and can't switch to other tasks (or connected via SSH), and there's nothing docker-related on the machine. How do you install docker and run a container?

Comment: But once you run those commands, there _will_ be docker on the machine?